# What widget do I need to use to create this effects in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

when I click on one of these yellow buttons  I need a the other buttons to appear in the image below

the yellow buttons are some categories and the buttons which appear after that are sub categories
[image]

I have no idea at all how would I do this so anything pointing me in the right direction would help

ps- the circle is nothing but the pointer please ignore it

Comment: what does the circle is ?

Comment: @MohammedHamdan the circle is nothing it is just the pointer you can ignore it

Comment: '' when I click on one of these buttons I need a dropdown structure like in the image below '' ==> there is no drop down in your second image . can you please be more specifying your need case ?

Comment: For the buttons, I would suggest to use [`Chip`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html) and for the menu [`PopupMenuButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html) or [`showMenu`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showMenu.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check [expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable), keep the yellow buttons on the `header` and rest (the content you want to show on tap) to `expanded` of the `ExpandablePanel`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the flutter document about `Chips` widget (link in below):
[Chips widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html)